# Reading a JSON array from file without modifications to the source in python

Tags: python, json, encoding

Stupid question, but takes a long time to figure out. I'm trying to post an API request to parse.com using python. The json array file is meant to be read by item and transferred. The problem is that whenever I do json.load(datafile) the text format is changed to the one that is not acceptable by the server. In particular instead of having {"field":"value"} I have now {u'field:'value'} which gives a server error. It must be some simple encoding problem, just having hard time figuring out.

Many thanks!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                        
import os
import json
APPLICATION_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
REST_API_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
File_to_Post="../Data/area.json"
command="cat %s" % (File_to_Post)


# Parse the JSON                                                                                                                                                                              
fileh = open(File_to_Post)
objs = json.load(fileh)

for o in objs:

    command1 = 'curl -X POST \                                                                                                                                                                
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: %s" \                                                                                                                                                        
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: %s"    \                                                                                                                                                       
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"          \                                                                                                                                           
     -d "%s" \                                                                                                                                                                                
      https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Areaobject' % (APPLICATION_ID, REST_API_KEY, o)
    os.system(command1)

fileh.close()
```

Comment: Got it :) Had to replace "%s" with \'%s\'. So simple :) And do json.dumps(o) also.

Answer (score 3):

When you load it, the JSON becomes a Python object. If you want to turn it *back* into JSON then you need to use `json.dump()` or `json.dumps()`.